# assign a object to select value - ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a object like this

```
var myObject = {'123':'something','345':'something else'}
```

I need to render it as:

```
<option value={'123':'something'}>something</option>
```

Here is what i have tried:

```
ng-options="someObj as label for (id,label) in myObject
```

Doesn't work!

The model gets the 'label' and not the whole object. Is it even possible to assign a object to value attribute of a SELECT element?

**EDIT**

Filter for object of the form: {'123':'something','345':'something else'}

```
.filter('putKeysandValues',function(){
        return function(options){
            var arr = [];
            angular.forEach(options,function(value,key){
                arr.push({'key':key,'label':value})
            });
            return arr;
        }
    });
```

Comment: what you are describing and the way you are describing it should be some clue that this won't actually work.  You don't have multiple objects, so you can't bind the model to 'the whole object', because `(id,label)` is not an object, it is a `key, value` pair.

Comment: I started to write out a modified version of `ng-options` but I'm actually confused by the attempt you posted.  what does `someObj` represent here in this example?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide an object with key & value attributes to ngOptions. For this you will need to modify the structure of your object to actually have this attributes.

One way is using a filter that returns a valid array for ngOptions:

```
ng-options="option.label for option in data.availableOptions | putKeyAndValue"
```

You can check out [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ddnCay6ytkM5IkTN0225?p=preview) with a working filter.

If input is:

```
[{'123':'something'}, {'345':'something else'}]
```

Then output is:

```
[{"123":"something","id":123,"label":"something","$$hashKey":"object:3"},{"345":"something else","id":345,"label":"something else","$$hashKey":"object:4"}]
```

If you want to remove the obsolete id attribute, then use [this filter](http://plnkr.co/edit/raUHWDzh9nR7451NkOHq?p=preview).

With input the same input, it will return this:

```
[{"id":123,"label":"something","$$hashKey":"object:3"},{"id":345,"label":"something else","$$hashKey":"object:4"}]
```

If you still need to return a new array, then do not do it on the filter. In that case you can process the data before passing it to the view, all in the controller [like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/xUWOkqqoIg5j6t29zrK0?p=preview).

With input:

```
{'123':'something', '345':'something else'}
```

Output this:

```
[{"id":123,"label":"something"},{"id":345,"label":"something else"}]
```

Comment: pls see my edit...I wrote a small filter like that. It works. But now i get a 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: The problem with your filter is that it's returning a new Array, that will make a new infinite loop since every time it is returned it is a new reference, even though the values remains the same. Because of that, I tried writing a new version of the filter, please tell me if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using **select as** something **for** a (key,value) **in** set of Values

```
ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in myObject"
```

This will put key into the option value and value into label. With that you need to also use ng-model and ngChange. Since you can't pass objects into values, idea is to do that in your controller.

```
<select ng-model="val" ng-change="changeVal(val)" ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in ops">
```

In your controller you already have myObject you are gonna add selected item and changeVal function

```
<script>
    var selectedObject;
    $scope.changeVal = function(val){
        selectedObject = {};
        selectedObject[val] = myObject[val];
    }
</script>
```

It's a workaround without putting object into value attr since it is a string.